# Lidar Dataset for Toe and Crest Detection

Tags: lidar, feature-class, terrain

I have read a paper on **[Terrain Toe and Crest Feature Detection and Labelling forAutonomous Mining](https://www.araa.asn.au/acra/acra2010/papers/pap116s1-file1.pdf)** and started working on building the code for this. But I am unable to find the dataset used in the paper.

Comment: You probably wont be able to find that exact dataset. If the method is rigorous enough any open cut mine elevation data should work.You might be able to get a dataset from a local or state government showing how a mine was a few years ago.

Comment: My main concern was to get the labelled data as Toe and crest.